# Is it best practice to enable both CloudFront and S3 access logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We are implementing a static site hosted in S3 behind CloudFront with OAI. Both CloudFront and S3 can have logging enabled and I'm trying to determine whether it is necessary/practical to have logging enabled for both.

The only S3 access that would not come from CloudFront should be site deployments from our CI/CD pipeline which may still be useful to log. It may be useful for that exact reason to find any unintended access that was not from CloudFront or deployments too? The downside of course is that there would be two sets of access logs that would mostly overlap and adding to the monthly bill.

We will need to make a decision on this, but curious what the consensus is out there.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CloudFront with origin Access Identity , then your bucket can be private to the world.

Only the OAI and any other users you want can have read access and denying any others access to the s3 bucket/files inside the bucket which host the static website.

Which means user around the world need to mandatorily come via cloud front and direct access to s3 bucket and it's files will be denied.

So if you have implemented it right , you do not need to have s3 access logging enabled.

However the value of security is only know once we face a disaster , just weigh in and take a decision.

References :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html